# Showing directly that the principal directions are going to be orthogonal

Tags: differential-geometry

So first of all, I know that the Weingarten map (which from now on I shall denote by $L$) is a symmetric linear operator, so there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvalues (Spectral Theorem).

I have been trying this concrete example for a while but I am just stuck and I would appreciate an extra pairs of eyes.

I will use the result that claims $L=G^{-1}H$ where $G$ is the matrix for the first fundamental form and $H$ is the matrix for the second fundamental form.

Our surface is given by $f(u,v)=(u\cos v, u\sin v , v)$. Then:

$f_u=(\cos v, \sin v, 0)$, $f_v=(-u\sin v, u \cos v, 1)$, $f_{uu}=(0,0,0)$, $f_{uv}=f_{vu}=(-\sin v, \cos v, 0)$, and $f_{vv}=(-u\cos v, -u \sin v, 0)$.

Thus, $g_{11}=f_u\cdot f_u=1$, $g_{12}=g_{21}=f_u\cdot f_v=0$, and $g_{22}=f_v\cdot f_v =u^2+1$.

Then, $f_u\times f_v=(\sin v, -\cos v, u)$, so $n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}(\sin v, -\cos v, u)$.

Then, $h_{11}=n\cdot f_{uu}=0$, $h_{12}=h_{21}=n\cdot f_{uv}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$, and $h_{22}=0$.

Then as $G^{_1}=Diag[1,\frac{1}{1+u^2}]$, we have that $L=G^{-1}H$, is: $L_{11}=0$, $L_{12}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$, $L_{21}=\frac{-1}{(u^2+1)^{3/2}}$, and $L_{22}=0$ (here is where I start to doubt because I thought I would always wind up with a symmetric matrix).

I get that the eigenvalues of this matrix are given by $\det(\lambda I-L)=\lambda^2-\frac{1}{(1+u^2)^2}$, so $k_1=\frac{1}{u^2+1}$, and $k_2=-k_1$. Then to find the first principal direction, we have to find the eigenvector correspoding to $k_1$, which turned out to be $(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}},1)$, and the other principal direction turned out to be $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}},1)$, which are not always orthogonal, so I dont know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with almost all of your computations.  That is, I agree with everything until you compute eigenvectors.

The eigenvectors for $k_1$ and $k_2$ are (according to Maple and my own work) respectively, $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Unfortunately, these seem to keep the same issue your calculation gives, right?  They seem to fail to be orthogonal (except when $u=0$ of course).  What's going on?

I claim that, in fact, these two vectors are everywhere orthgonal *as measured by someone living on your coordinate patch*.  The key point is that all of this has been expressed in the basis $\{f_u, f_v\}$, but this is **not** an orthonormal basis.  If it was, you'd have $G = I$ everywhere.

So, the dot product $\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \end{bmatrix} \right\rangle$ is **not** $1-\frac{1}{1+u^2}$, but it must take the metric $G$ into account.

The dot product is actually given by \begin{align*} \left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \end{bmatrix} \right\rangle &= G_{11}\cdot 1\cdot 1 + G_{22} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\cdot \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} \\ &= 1+(1+u^2)\left(\frac{-1}{1+u^2} \right) \\ &= 1-1 \\ &= 0.\end{align*}

In other words, your two eigenvectors *are* orthogonal with respect to the metric on your coordinate patch.

Comment: If any latex guru reads this, I used the `\left` command to size the `\langle` commands.  This worked great in the usual (single dollar sign) environment, but the `\langle` in the align environment is too small.  What's the best way to adjust this?